# Openshift complete secret deletion

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to remove some "secrets" objects in my Openshift project. Based on the documentation when you issue:

```
oc delete secret secret-name
```

Openshift will delete the secret identified by secret-name and generate a new one in its place.

How can I completely delete the secret without having a new one generated automatically?

Comment: The recreation only applies to secrets that are associated with a service account. That is, the special secrets that OpenShift created when you create a service account. It doesn't apply to your own secrets.

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete a `secret` that has a `service account` associated to the secret, you must delete the service account first.

If you are looking at the secret you want to delete, you can find the associated service account:

Finding the associated service account:
`oc get secret secret-name -o json`

There is an annotation `kubernetes.io/service-account.name` and the value of this annotation is the service account.

Find the service account name may be easier using `jq` to parse the json:

`oc get secret secret-name -o json | jq '.metadata.annotations."kubernetes.io/service-account.name"'`

You can delete a service account using:
`oc delete sa my-sa`

Answer (score 0):

**To show a basic example:**

```
$ oc get secrets | grep postgres
postgresql-persistent-parameters7albb           Opaque                                1         53d
postgresql-persistent-parameters9dlte           Opaque                                1         118d
postgresql-persistent-parameterscow6t           Opaque                                1         98d
postgresql-persistent-tczfh-credentials-jh87i   Opaque                                4         41d
postgresql-vault                                Opaque                                3         53d
```

**Delete a secret using `oc delete secret` command**:

```
$ oc delete secret postgresql-vault
secret "postgresql-vault" deleted
```

**The deleted secret is not available now**

```
$ oc get secrets | grep postgres
postgresql-persistent-parameters7albb           Opaque                                1         53d
postgresql-persistent-parameters9dlte           Opaque                                1         118d
postgresql-persistent-parameterscow6t           Opaque                                1         98d
postgresql-persistent-tczfh-credentials-jh87i   Opaque                                4         41d
```